# How to watch nsIHandlerService.store(handlerInfo)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I need to notify tabs whenever someone does `store` on `handlerInfo` of `mailto` protocol. So I can notify my tabs that it was updated and it should refersh to show latest information.

This is what I need to watch:

```
var handlerInfo = Cc['@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIExternalProtocolService).getProtocolHandlerInfo('mailto');
Cc['@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService)store(handlerInfo)
```

I checked MXR and found this:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/uriloader/exthandler/nsIHandlerService.idl#78

```
68   /**
69    * Save the preferred action, preferred handler, possible handlers, and
70    * always ask properties of the given handler info object to the datastore.
71    * Updates an existing record or creates a new one if necessary.
72    *
73    * Note: if preferred action is undefined or invalid, then we assume
74    * the default value nsIHandlerInfo::useHelperApp.
75    *
76    * @param aHandlerInfo  the handler info object
77    */
78   void store(in nsIHandlerInfo aHandlerInfo);
```

It says it updates the `datastore` and there's no code in the `store` function. I was wondering how can I watch update to this `datastore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you found is not the implementation, but just the interface defining the API.

[The actual implementation](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/uriloader/exthandler/nsHandlerService.js#376) is in JavaScript and actually kind of crusty, legacy code.

There is no supported way of watching changes (no observers, or such). So you're essentially left with either

- Overriding (proxying) the whole service.
- Polling the service repeatedly.
- Or checking the underlying file.

(Short of trying to get a patch into mozilla-central; which I don't think would be very welcome at this point because rewriting the whole implementation to not use RDF anymore has probably far more priority :p)

*Edit* As @Blagoh, suggest, one could *potentially* add an `RDF` observer by opening the `UMimTyp` file as a data source again and calling [`AddObserver` to add an `nsIRDFObserver`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/b50bb656674e/rdf/base/nsIRDFDataSource.idl#l114) that will be notified on new assertion (new values) and changes.

While observers are per instance and normally when creating another instance you'll not be notified on changes to previous and later instances, the RDF service actually caches named data sources when they where previously registered via `.RegisterDataSource`, which [the XML data source backend seems to do](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/b50bb656674e/rdf/base/nsRDFXMLDataSource.cpp#l594). So calling `.GetDataSource(Blocking)` again for the same `UMimTyp` file should actually always return the same instance again, so observers get added to the right, "shared"/cached data source instance.

I didn't really try this, however, but it seems promising.

Comment: Ah so it updates a rdf file, so I can use file watcher once its done (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=958280) im going to go look for the rdf file its updating right now. if u know off the top of your head where i can find it plz share, otherwise no worries im going to be doing some digging anyways.

Comment: What about `AddObserver` of `gRDF.GetDataSourceBlocking(fileHandler.getURLSpecFromFile(file))` here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/mozapps/downloads/content/helperApps.js#87 and @Noitidart this mxr link tells you where to get file.

Comment: @Blagoh. Great idea! I amended my answer trying to ponder why this should actually work.

Comment: Thanks guys. Btw the mime type rdf file was at `FileUtils.getFile('UMimTyp', [])` which for me is `C:\Documents and Settings\Noit\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\vr10qb8s.default\mimeTypes.rdf`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys this works for me:

```
/* start - aRDFObserver structure */
// is a nsIRDFObserver
var aRDFObserver = {
  onChange: function(aDataSource, aSource, aProperty, aOldTarget, aNewTarget) { 
   console.log('onChange', {'aSource': aSource, 'aProperty': aProperty});
    if (aSource.ValueUTF8 == 'urn:scheme:handler:mailto') {
     //refresh my page
    }
  }
};
/* end - aRDFObserver structure */

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
var rdfs = Cc['@mozilla.org/rdf/rdf-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIRDFService);
var file = FileUtils.getFile('UMimTyp', []);
var fileHandler = Services.io.getProtocolHandler('file').QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileProtocolHandler);
var ds = rdfs.GetDataSourceBlocking(fileHandler.getURLSpecFromFile(file));

ds.AddObserver(aRDFObserver);
```

How does it look?

The problem with it is `onChange` fires like 4 times as 4 different attributes are changed on the rdf. Is there anyway to know when the last `onChange` fired? Otherwise my page is refreshed 4 times lol.

Also should I test `aSource.ValueUTF8`? or `aSource.Value`? they both look to me to hold same value.

Here is the structure of complete `nsIRDFObserver`: [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-RDFObserverWatchMimeTypesInfo.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/e3bfc95e923456176d0d)

Comment: For the 4 times thrown etc, what I did was time the max time it takes between onChange calls. I saw it was around 160ms most of the times its 1ms. So I do a setTimeout for 500ms and clear the timeout and restart it every on change. so only 500ms after the final change it will do the change. If you guys have any other ideas for that please share that would be awesome to see how others would do it.